# Best practice for using BindingExpression in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have some UI elements that do some UI-specific work in code behind then update a binding in the data context.

WPF Elements:

```
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
             Text="{Binding PartNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
             Name="ui_partNumber"
             FontSize="35"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Content="OK"
            Click="PartOKClick"
            FontSize="20"
            Width="150" />
```

Code behind:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handle updating the view model with the part number
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void PartOKClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

  //Get the textbox's binding expression
  BindingExpression be = ui_partNumber.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);

  if (Condition) {
    //Update part number binding
    be.UpdateSource();

    //Animate to next state
    InAnimate(ui_partGrid.Name);
    OutAnimate(ui_whichPartNumber.Name);
  }
  else {
    //Discard the text in the textbox 
    be.UpdateTarget();

    //Animate to notification state
    InAnimate(ui_invalidLocation.Name);
  }
}
```

The property in my ViewModel looks like:

```
public string PartNumber{
    get { return _partNumber; }
    set { _partNumber = value; OnPropertyChanged("PartNumber"); }
}
```

I'm using explicit binding and only updating the source if things check out, otherwise I'm just reverting to the original binding.

The question is, is this the best way to work with the binding explicitly?  If I'm getting the BindingExpression of 100 elements of varying types, do I need to do it by hand each time?  Would I be able to do it in a more reusable way?

Comment: Do you have a solution for your unanswered question? Maybe one `Explicit` option for grid instead of all controls and calling `UpdateSource` once for all bounded controls. Simply for `Cancel` button

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are willing to check the value entered in the `TextBox` and update the binding only if it is valid, right?

Well luckily, WPF has a built-in error handling process which is way cleaner that what you did there. You should read something about `IDataErrorInfo`

[This article is pretty clear about how to use it](http://tarundotnet.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-idataerrorinfo-in-wpf/)

As an example in your case, you'd have something like this:

WPF Elements:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1"
         Text="{Binding PartNumber, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
         Name="ui_partNumber"
         FontSize="35"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
<Button Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Content="OK"
        Click="PartOKClick"
        FontSize="20"
        Width="150" />
```

In your `ViewModel`, you should have this:

```
public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.Equals(columnName, "PartNumber", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || columnName == string.Empty)
                {
                    // Here, IDataErrorInfo is checking the property "PartNumber" bound to your TextBox
                    if (this.IsPartNumberValid(ui_partNumber.Text))
                    {
                        // Not valid: return any error message (string.Empty = no error, otherwise it will be seen as not valid)
                        return "Not valid!";
                    }
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

This should do the trick for you: if the string "Not valid!" is returned, the `TextBox` will be displayed with a red border and the `Binding` won't be updated

Comment: I've worked with IDataErrorInfo in the past, but it doesn't fit my application here.  My example is simple, but sometimes I need to do more work in my code behind aside from doing some animations (which I realize I could do with data triggers in this case).  I opted for explicit bindings because I needed some more liberty with validation and less "triggery" overhead I was experiencing with more strict MVVM.  So my question is more regarding use of BindingExpression. +1 for the suggestion

Comment: What needs would possibly prevent you from using a traditional `IDataErrorInfo` + `Triggers` ? Since you mention best practices, I believe using them is part of the best practices for this mater. Maybe your problem can be overcome using this, if you can add some code/details

Comment: IDataErrorInfo is fine and there's nothing preventing me from using it in this instance.  My question isn't regarding data validation though, it's about explicitly updating a binding.  Another simple example would be adding a confirmation UI element before updating the binding: "Are you sure you wish to foo?" Yes = update source, No = update target.

Comment: I have same question, and simply user passed all validation but just clicked `cancel` button instead of `save` button and I would like to ignore all changes in bounded controls and displaying original data from source. In this case `DataErrorInfo`+ `Triggers` will not help because all entered data is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you forced to use explicit binding? Why not do the validation in your ViewModel and then fire off an OnPropertyChanged("BindingParameter") only if you need an update?

Something like this (in VB):

```
Property prop as Object
  Get
   return _prop
  End Get 
  Set(ByVal value As Object)
    If your_validation_check(value) then
      _prop = value
      OnPropertyChanged("prop") 'INotifyPropertyChanged
    End If
  End Set 
End Property
```

Comment: Because I don't want the ViewModel to consume an update until the View is ready to send one.

Comment: You could use a weak messaging system like in MVVM foundation and have a listener in your viewmodel which fires off the OnPropertyChanged event.